# The ultimate organism!

Tags: creature-design, science-fiction, space

So I've created this creature I'm calling the Shod, short for shadow of death. This creature lives in space and looks like a massive, black cloud. Inside the Shod, particles move at immense speeds, constant levels of radiation in all parts of the EM spectrum, electric currents, magnetic fields, and heavy gravity. The core of the Shod is super dense, and functions as the brain. They rarely move their entire bodies, but prefer to manipulate their bodies into thin, easily manipulated tendrils. They use planets to reproduce and incubate their young, and are capable of wiping out star systems easily. Shod consume stars and planets for fuel, and are capable of manipulating their bodies at will.

However, since the body of this creature is mostly in a gaseous or plasma state, it is constantly in danger from things like solar winds and other types of space weather that could disperse at least part of its body. So what I'm looking for is some type of space phenomenon that would not only threaten a creature like this, but would also ensure that it is unable to go wherever it wants. Specifically, I want to keep it away from a certain part of the galaxy, so that space travel is much safer there, but far more dangerous past a certain point.

I would prefer something natural, as opposed to artificial alien or human made, and as close to reality as possible.

Comment: You limit a creature like this by writing limits into it. This seems line another [unstoppable creature question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4317/what-to-do-about-unstoppable-questions).

Comment: The biggest limit for any space creature is the speed of light and the energy requirements to reach significant fractions of the speed of light.  It can be tens or hundreds of thousands of years to travel between solar systems, so how practical is it for them to devour a galaxy ?

Comment: This has been edited and automatically put in the reopen queue, but it still looks completely opinion based to me.  You want us to postulate how a planet or star would react if in a massive particle accelerator?  You've created a god-like creature.  You need to give it a compensating weakness, though I can't imagine what it would be.  Anything as large as your suggesting would absorb galaxies by its own mass/gravity, no matter what limitations were imposed.  Stuff would litterally stick to its exterior.  Does it have a tongue to lick it all off?

Comment: I'm thinking you're right. Maybe I've asked the wrong question here, as it does require a whole lot of assumptions and guesswork. However mentioning the gravity that this would possess does give me some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Predators, disease, infant mortality, and, even, cannibalism. I suspect if they're that massive they can only move very, very slowly. The question suggests their mass could be anywhere from from a planet's up to whole planetary system. Moving that amount of mass will take utterly vast amounts of energy. Could be a long, long time between meals.

Of course, any galaxy with sapient life & advanced technology will tend to keep them under control.